# Feeding a nested JSON to rapidJSON document resulting in kParseErrorDocumentRootNotSingular

Tags: json, c++11, rapidjson

I'm preparing a function that will return the value of a key in a nested JSON. The problem is that I'm getting the nested JSON's content as a string and that is not something I can change.

For example: 
{"remote": {"ip": "127.0.0.1", "port": 58811}}

The content of "remote" is a nested JSON and my code needs to return the value of "ip". Upstream, this nested JSON is turned into a string and passed on to my function.

My code is:

```
string sampleInputVal = "\"remote\": {\"ip\": \"127.0.0.1\", \"port\": 58811}";
map<string, string> inputMap;

inputMap.emplace("key","remote");
inputMap.emplace("nestedKey","IP");

string getValNestedJSON(string inputVal, map<string, string> inputParameters)
{
    Document inputJSON;
    inputJSON.Parse(inputVal.c_str());

    return inputJSON[inputParameters["nestedKey"].c_str()].GetString();
}
```

A you can guess, `sampleInputVal` is just something I'm using to test the function, but I think the escape characters are messing up rapidjson because I'm getting kParseErrorDocumentRootNotSingular.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The sampleInputVal was wrong, it needs to be `"{\"IP\":\"127.0.0.1\", \"port\":2.34}"`

Here is the code that works and is prepared for values that are not just strings:

```
string getValNestedJSON(string inputVal, map<string, string> inputParameters)
{
    string output;
    Document inputJSON;
    inputJSON.Parse(inputVal.c_str());
    const auto nestedKeyVal = inputParameters["nestedKey"].c_str();
    if (inputJSON[nestedKeyVal].IsString())
        output = inputJSON[nestedKeyVal].GetString();
    else if (inputJSON[nestedKeyVal].IsInt())
        output = to_string(inputJSON[nestedKeyVal].GetInt());
    else if (inputJSON[nestedKeyVal].IsDouble())
        output = to_string(inputJSON[nestedKeyVal].GetDouble());
    else if (inputJSON[nestedKeyVal].IsBool())
        output = to_string(inputJSON[nestedKeyVal].GetBool());
    else if (inputJSON[nestedKeyVal].IsUint())
        output = to_string(inputJSON[nestedKeyVal].GetUint());
    else if (inputJSON[nestedKeyVal].IsInt64())
        output = to_string(inputJSON[nestedKeyVal].GetInt64());
    else if (inputJSON[nestedKeyVal].IsUint64())
        output = to_string(inputJSON[nestedKeyVal].GetUint64());
    else if (inputJSON[nestedKeyVal].IsUint64())
        output = to_string(inputJSON[nestedKeyVal].GetUint64());
    else
        output = "Value in nested key cannot be obtained";

    return output;
}
```